# scala insert to redis gives task not serializable

Tags: scala, cassandra, redis, spark-streaming, scala-collections

I have a following code :-

```
case class event(imei: String, date: String, gpsdt: String,
             entrygpsdt: String,lastgpsdt: String) 

val result = rdd.map(row => {
val imei = row.getString(0)
val date = row.getString(1)
val gpsdt = row.getString(2)

event(imei, date, gpsdt, lastgpsdt ,"2018-04-06 10:10:10")
}).collect()

 val collection = sc.parallelize(result)
 collection.saveToCassandra("db", "table", SomeColumns("imei", "date", "gpsdt", "lastgpsdt", "dt")
```

This works fine . So, now I'm inserting this result value into cassandra but I want to insert part of each rdd into Redis as well . When, I'm trying to use redis insert inside loop it gives an error that Task is not serializable

I want something like this :-

```
case class event(imei: String, date: String, gpsdt: String,
         entrygpsdt: String,lastgpsdt: String) 
val result = rdd.map(row => { 
val imei = row.getString(0)
val date = row.getString(1)
val gpsdt = row.getString(2)
val zscore = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis
val value = row.getString(0) + ',' + row.getString(2)
val key = row.getString(1)
client.zadd(key , zscore, value)
event(imei, date, gpsdt, lastgpsdt ,"2018-04-06 10:10:10")
}).collect()

val collection = sc.parallelize(result)
collection.saveToCassandra("db", "table", SomeColumns("imei", "date", "gpsdt", "lastgpsdt", "dt")
```

So, How Can I do that , "client" is object of scala redis library.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Since no answer was provided by anyone. I found the solution for my case. Don't know whether the approach is good or not but it worked for me. So, idea is collect data by iterating over RDD . You'll be given a result of Array[event]. So, now again start a loop on result and insert each row in Redis. and finally "result" in cassandra. This flow is solving my both purpose that I was looking for.
Thanks,

Comment: I don't think it is the right approach to collect to a driver, how did you create the client instance and how. Can you share a bit more code ?

Comment: val clients = new RedisClientPool("192.168.0.78", 6379)
clients.withClient {
            client =>
              {  client.zadd(key , zscore, value) } }

Comment: Did you defined outside the foreachRDD in streaming ?

Comment: Yes defined outside.

Comment: I think thats causing the serializable error, Try defining inside the foreach. If it is outside than the executer does not find tha object initialization and throws error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169639/discussion-between-aditya-jain-and-shankar-koirala).

Answer (score 0):

The `serializable` exception is generally caused due to the connection object creation.

However your code does not include, I guess you have created the `client` object outside the `foreachRDD`

If so the client object is `created` in driver and `foreach` is executed in `executor` where it cannot find the `client` object and occurs exception `task not serializable.`

What you can do is create the `client` object inside `foreach`, But this creates a `connection` for each `record`, which is also not good for performance.

So what you can do is

```
rdd.foreachPartition(partition => {
     //Create a connection here for redis 
     partition.foreach(record => {
         //send the data here 
     })
})
```

Hope this helps!